# moment avoid time zone after calculation

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

I need to make calcul with date in moment but i just want to count days, i don't care about hours, timezone or whatever.

I store date in date without timezone, but when i made calculations with moment, I always have problem with hours changing.
My computer is in France and we change hour 2 time per years.

I found some way with parseZone() and startOf('day'), but my code become very messy and i'm looking for the best way to do what i want.

For example, this code : http://jsfiddle.net/zn2pcg65/2/

```
var a = moment('2022-01-05T00:00:00.000Z');
console.log(a.toDate().toISOString());
var b = a.add(3,'M');
console.log(b.toDate().toISOString());
```

give me :

```
"2022-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"
"2022-04-04T23:00:00.000Z"
```

I wanted "2022-04-05".

What is the best way to do calculations with date without having this kind of side effect ?

Comment: Are you using the [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone) lib? If so, how are you setting the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using ISO format, so what is ISO format

ISO:
The International Organization for Standardization (ISO) date format is a standard way to express a numeric calendar date that eliminates ambiguity. For example, North Americans usually write the month before the date.

for more: https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/ISO-date-format

To solve your problems you need to parse your date to UTC time.

What its etc:

Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is the basis for civil time today. This 24-hour time standard is kept using highly precise atomic clocks combined with the Earth's rotation.

for more: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html

Here the solution you need:

```
var a = moment('2022-01-05T00:00:00.000Z').utc();
console.log('a: ',a.toDate().toISOString());
var b = a.add(3,'M');
console.log('b', b.toDate().toISOString());

//more espesific format: 
//a.format('MM-DD-YYYY') output 01-05-2022

//b.format('MM-DD-YYYY') output 04-05-2022
```